# Can I proxy a ServiceStack Service?

Tags: servicestack, servicestack-bsd

I'm wondering if it's possible to have ServiceStack use an AOP-proxied service, instead of the main implementation.  I would like to avoid having the class that inherits from `ServiceStack.ServiceInterface.Service` simply be a wrapper, if possible.  It looks to me like it will need to be, but I thought it wouldn't hurt to ask, to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

I am looking for a way to achieve this, to proxy the services of a ServiceStack app.

Till now what I have learned is that: The only way we can generate a proxy to a service like

```
[Route("/reqstars")]
public class AllReqstars : IReturn<List<Reqstar>> { }

public class ReqstarsService : Service
{
    public virtual List<Reqstar> Any(AllReqstars request) 
    {
        return Db.Select<Reqstar>();
    }
}
```

Is using a Custom Service Generation Strategy. And generating proxies of IService interface with class target and marking all the method of the service as virtual.

I have not tested this yet and even I do not know (and this is what I am researching for now) if ServiceStack can handle a service generator delegate so I can use Castle's DynamicProxy.

Good luck!